# Do sages have unlimited time vision?

Tags: rishi, time

Sage(Rishi) in Hinduism has capacity to view and feel the events and happenings in past and future.

We know that universe(s) has neither beginning nor ending. So the time is infinite in both the directions.

In this context, does a sage has capacity to view infinitely or do the capacity varies from sage to sage?

Comment: "We know that universe has neither beginning nor ending. " This is not true.

Comment: I mean Brahman creates it and annihilate it and do it again and again.... In that at there is neither starting point nor ending point(not for a particular creation). A particular creation may have starting And ending point...

Comment: You're right. There is no start or end to Universe.

Comment: @AkshayS no that is not true. Every universe has a beginning and an end.

Comment: @Wikash_ I mean the current universe will have end, but a new universe will start...

Comment: @Wikash_ What I mean is that creation and destruction will run forever

Comment: @hanugm yes, that is correct.

Comment: The answer to your question is easy. A Rishi cannot look infinite time ahead. There is a limit due to the rules of the material world.

Comment: Take the best Rishi or Warg ( Game of thrones) who can look into the future. Say they cover 40 years into the future and know what is going to happen up to 40 years. Now, God has the option to not progress anything after 40 years and leave it blank and  right when they start Looking again after a few days then Pause them and create the future then on....is the right way to understand it...so there is literally no concept of infinite time. When he pauses it, he could design the future ‘as appropriate’

Answer (score 1):

1)   **It is a misconception that every sage will attain certain powers/siddhi.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi

The Ultimate aim of any spiritual practice/saadhana is to reach a transcendental state or ABSOLUTE BLISS, wherein the sage will remain unperturbed by good/bad, happiness/sadness, etc.

> नान्यं गुणेभ्यः कर्तारं यदा द्रष्टानुपश्यति।
>
> गुणेभ्यश्च परं वेत्ति मद्भावं सोऽधिगच्छति।।14.19।।
>
> When the witness sees none other than the alities as the agent, and knows that which is superior [i.e. different from.] to the alities, he attains My nature.
>
> समदुःखसुखः स्वस्थः समलोष्टाश्मकाञ्चनः।
>
> तुल्यप्रियाप्रियो धीरस्तुल्यनिन्दात्मसंस्तुतिः।।14.24।।
>
> He to whom sorrow and happiness are alike, who is established in his own Self, to whom a lump of earth, iron and gold are the same, to whom the agreeable and the disagreeable are the same, who is wise, to whom censure and his own praise are the same;

2)  A sage may attain Siddhi/powers or may be attain powers parallel to attaining ABSOLUTE BLISS, according to **prarabdha** (stored merit) of that body.

Sri Shirdi Sai and Sri Ramana Maharshi both attained ABSOLUTE BLISS.  While Shri Shirdi Sai exhibited powers, Sri Ramana Maharshi did not.

Further, the sages will give least importance to the powers and always advised their disciples to steer away from desiring/acquiring powers, which are nothing before the ABSOLUTE BLISS.

3)  When a sage attains an ABSOLUTE BLISS, which is also called the God/TIME, there will be no bar as to how far they can travel in time.  Again the rider is if they wish so.

The sages will treat the past as nothing but ashes, and dwelling in the past events, according to their advice, does not serve any purpose.

Comment: "here will be no bar as to how far they can travel in time. " How do you know this?

Comment: @Wikash_: I have gone through biographies of many saints/sages.  Some of them narrated at times to devotees about incidents pertaining to them  that took place even  a decade ago . So surmised so.  Further, once merged in TIME,  even Sri Krishna said in BG about how he taught the ancestors.

Comment: That still does not give proof to your claim.

Comment: @Wikash_: In spiritual realm, we cannot produce proof for everything.  Scriptures say about air as "namaste vayo . tvameva pratyaxam brahmasi....".  How air can become BRAHMA?  what is the proof for the that?

Comment: " what is the proof for the that?" Yes, there is no proof for this in the scriptures. So we either infer it or give the honest answer: "I do not know"/"the scriptures do not answer this question".

Comment: @Wikash_: I repeat, though we can perceive, we cannot show evidence for everything in spiritual realm.

Comment: Yes I understand but if there is not evidence one can assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sri Brahma-samhita says; YES !!

> "prem-anjancchurit bhakti-vilochanen, santah sadaiva hrideshu vilokayanti; yam shyam-sunderam achintya-gunn svarupam, govindam adipurusham tam aham bhajami." ver# 38, chp# 5.

The pure devotees under trance, the saints, always see in their heart of hearts with the eye of devotion tinged with the salve of love, the events of eternity beyond the time. I worship Govinda, the primeval Lord, who is Shyam-sunder, the most beautiful, with inconceivable innumerable transcendental attributes.

Comment: Please translate...

Comment: @hanugm ok. we have appended the answer with the translation.